# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange only called once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `UITextField` with a clear button and *autocorrection* enabled. If I enter "Thg", autocorrect suggests "The". Now if I press the clear button `textFieldShouldClear` gets called and then `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` gets called with *replacementString* equal to "The" and thats it. The `UITextField` is now blank. Shouldn't `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` get called again with *replacementString* equal to ""?

Answer (score 3):

When `textFieldShouldClear` gets called set the `UITextField.text` to @"" and return NO. This way `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` will get called.